# Prove that limit does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Let $f$ be a bounded function and continous in $[a, \infty )$
$M=\sup(f(x)), m=\inf(f(x))$ when $x\in [a, \infty )$
and suppose that $M,m$ are not in image of $f$.

Prove that limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x))$ does not exist.

Comment: A good question here needs some context and/or evidence of your own effort.  Can you add some to improve the question and avoid closure?

Comment: For example, what happens if assume $M = m$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

There are monotone sequences $(x_n)$ and $(x_n')$ such that $f(x_n) \to M$ and $f(x_n') \to m$ as $n \to \infty$. Can $x_n$ and $x_n'$ be nonincreasing or converge to finite numbers?